# variations of objects: to be or not to be a tensor

Tags: tensors, calculus-of-variations

On [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268211/why-is-the-variation-of-a-christoffel-symbol-a-tensor#new-answer?newreg=2211a0e5ad224cc78fe0ee838eeba2cb) we find that a variation of the connection $\Gamma_{\nu\sigma}^\rho$ (not a tensor) is a tensor (it obeys the the tensor transformation equation).

On [physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63856/why-vary-the-action-with-respect-to-the-inverse-metric) we find that $\delta g_{\mu\nu} = -g_{\mu\rho}g_{\nu\sigma}\delta g^{\rho\sigma}$. So a variation of the metric (a tensor) is not a tensor (it does not obey the rule about raising and lowering indices).

This seems like a minefield. Do I have to check the tensor-ness of every object I vary? Or is there some rule?

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle everything on a case by case basis, but you don't always have to go back to the tensor transformational law. The trick is to remember a few results, such as that $\delta\nabla_aX=\nabla_a\delta X$ and $\delta\partial_aX=\partial_a\delta X$ (and that $\nabla$ sends tensors to tensors, as can be proven from their definition), $\delta(XY)=X\delta Y+(\delta X)Y$, and $\delta\delta_a^b=0$. Thus$$\Gamma_{ab}^cV_c=(\partial_a-\nabla_a)V_b\implies\delta\Gamma_{ab}^c\cdot V_c+\Gamma_{ab}^c\delta V_c=(\partial_a-\nabla_a)\delta V_b=\Gamma_{ab}^c\delta V_c\implies\delta\Gamma_{ab}^c\cdot V_c=0.$$Finally, this contraction with arbitrary vectors to form a (vanishing) rank-$2$ tensor implies $\delta\Gamma_{ab}^c$ transforms as a tensor (again, this is easily verified from the definition). By contrast, when no obvious proof a quantity transforms as a tensor can be obtained with such tricks, it's worth trying to prove the opposite from the definition, as you can with the second example you gave.

Comment: Thanks and the bit about $\delta\nabla_aX=\nabla_a\delta X$ is  very useful. I had just come across $\nabla_a\delta X$ and was wondering what to do with the covariant derivative of a non-tensor. Now I know.

Comment: Or maybe not so useful. The expression I am challenged by is $$
\nabla_\nu\left({\delta g}^{\lambda\sigma}\right)
$$So $\nabla_\nu\delta X=\delta\nabla_\nu X$ implies that $\nabla_\nu\left({\delta g}^{\lambda\sigma}\right)=0$ by metric compatibility. Must we say that $X,\delta X$ are both tensors in $\nabla_\nu\delta X=\delta\nabla_\nu X$? What then does $\nabla_n\left({\delta g}^{ls}\right)$ mean? For the time being I will interpret it as a shorthand for$$
\mathrm{\partial}_n{\delta g}^{ls}+\Gamma_{nm}^l{\delta g}^{ms}+\Gamma_{nm}^s{\delta g}^{lm}
$$

Comment: @GeorgeKeeling Since$$\begin{align}0&=[\delta,\,\nabla_a]V^b\\&=[\delta,\,\nabla_a](g^{bc}V_c)\\&=([\delta,\,\nabla_a]g^{bc})V_c+g^{bc}\underbrace{[\delta,\,\nabla_a]V_c}_{0}\end{align}$$for any vector $V$, $[\delta,\,\nabla_a]g^{bc}=0$.

Comment: I assume that [] is a commutator so $\delta\nabla_aX=\nabla_a\delta X$ is the same as $\left[\delta,\nabla_a\right]X=0$ . So since you have shown $\left[\delta,\nabla_a\right]g^{bc}=0$ then $X,\delta X$ do not have to both be tensors. My previous comment was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have been very confused by all this!
It is not true that $\nabla_a\delta X=\delta\nabla_aX$ as J.G. says. It is easy to show by using the usual formula for the covariant derivative that, for example $$
\nabla_a\left({\delta V}^b\right)=\delta\left(\nabla_aV^b\right)+V^c\delta\Gamma_{ac}^b
$$It is also not true that $\delta\Gamma_{ac}^b=0$. J.G.'s proof of it relied on $\nabla_a\delta X=\delta\nabla_aX$.

It is also not true that ${\delta g}_{ab}\ ,\ {\delta g}^{ab}$ are not tensors as I said. They are tensors but they are different tensors. One is the variation of the metric, the other the variation of the inverse metric. For total clarity one might replace ${\delta g}^{ab}$ by ${\delta\bar{g}}^{ab}$ or even ${\delta\left(g^{-1}\right)}^{ab}$.